# Lua script error while putting line comments with redis

Tags: lua, redis

I am getting a strange error with lua script while running it on redis cluster.

the following script

```
--if keyCount ~= 1 or  KEYS[1] == nil then

--end
```

throws error:

```
(error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:3: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near '<eof>'
```

Following is the redis-cli command I am using:

```
./redis-cli -h HOST -p PORT SCRIPT LOAD "$(cat 2.lua)"
```

It looks like a bug to me, how come a fully commented script needs an 'end' at the end!! Has someone seen this?

PS: I am posting the most reduced version of script where I am able to reproduce the issue, actually faced it in much bigger script while putting the line comments. Putting the multi line comment like --[[]] solves the issue, but this shouldn't be occurring at the first place! I am using Lua 5.1 and redis 3.0.x

Comment: Mhm. It definitely sounds like a bug. Could You please clarify the environment (OS, specifically)? There is slim chance that `cat` adds some crap You don't actually need.

Comment: It should not make a difference, but doesn't redis use Lua 5.1?

Comment: Lua v5.1 indeed and there is a recent fix to Redis that smells familiar: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2951

Comment: The current version of redis, 3.0.7, contains this fix.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline Trailing new line should help you.

Comment: Confirmed that its a bug with redis 3.0.5 (running Lua 5.1) , the issue is fixed in redis 3.0.7

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed that its a bug with redis 3.0.5 (running Lua 5.1) , the issue is fixed in redis 3.0.7